# trying to use if, elseif, else loop in checkbox

Tags: c#

i am trying to make a program in c#, in which the values of check boxes are retrieved from csv file.I have 4 check boxes and all of them are true or false according to the conditions in csv file. My question is i am using

```
if (strProg[a] == "JC")
{ 
    chkJogging.Checked = true; 
    chkCycling.Checked = true;
}
else if(strProg[a] =="C")
{
   chkCycling == true
}
else if(strProg[a] == "WK")
{
    chkWeightLoss.Checked = true;
    chkKoxing.Checked = true
}
else
{
    chkBoxing.Checked = false; 
    chkJogging.Checked = false;
    chkCycling.Checked = false;
    chkWeightLoss.Checked = false
}
```

But for some reason the last one 'else' loop is not working. Thanks.

Comment: Not working is meaningless. Please explain what is not working....

Comment: Are you quite new to programming? an "else loop" is an odd term, imo :P

Comment: To answer your question it's very difficult to know where to start. It would be very helpful if you include the "loop" part. Also, change the name of your index variable to mean something (don't use a) use something like (columnIndex, or lineIndex, or what ever it is.)

Comment: As it stands above your code cannot be compiled. In the condition for "C" there is a syntax error. Did you mean `chkCycling.Checked=true;`? Also your code lacks of numerous semicolons

Comment: There are no loops in this code...

Comment: And, chkKoxing.Checked is suspicious too, did you mean chkBoxing.Checked?

Comment: oh well, I think that all these comments together are giving the answer....

Comment: else { throw new Exception("Undefined program type"); }

Comment: If I were you, I would write the names of the checkboxes and their values to scv and directly set their values with a single for loop without any if-else conditional clauses (yes, if-else is not a loop, it is a conditional clause).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use IF-ELSE This way.

read this : [SWITCH-CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx)

try this :

```
switch (strProg[a])
            {
                case "JC":
                    chkJogging.Checked = true;
                    chkCycling.Checked = true;
                    break;
                case "C":
                    chkCycling.Checked = true;
                    break;
                case "WK":
                    chkWeightLoss.Checked = true;
                    chkKoxing.Checked = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    chkBoxing.Checked = false;
                    chkJogging.Checked = false;
                    chkCycling.Checked = false;
                    chkWeightLoss.Checked = false;
                    break;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing '.Checked' here, so my guess is probably your code is breakin at this point.

```
else if(strProg[a] =="C")
{
chkCycling == true
}
```

try to change it with

```
else if(strProg[a] =="C")
{
chkCycling.Checked == true
}
```

and see if it works.